# Why does this Rails app fails to deploy to GCLOUD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, gcloud, app-engine-flexible

While attempting to deploy a non-default service to gcloud application with the command:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
```

I get the error (right after all gems finish installing):

```
...
Step #1: /opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/google-api-client- 
0.36.4/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:228:in `check_status': forbidden: The caller does 
not have permission (Google::Apis::ClientError)
....

Step #1:    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/rcloadenv:22:in `<main>'
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c gem install rcloadenv && rbenv rehash && rcloadenv flex-env- 
config >> .env' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud- 
builders/docker@sha256:853164af9dfd5ea4613401df48ad77b61bcb2c101b4e5de261c8300ecdd6eb47" 
failed: exit status 1
```

Note that I performed this process for another service (default) minutes before this one, which tells me my local configuration is working to some extent.
Could I be missing any extra step specific to a Rails Application ?

### **app.yaml**

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby
service: api

runtime_config:
  dotenv_config: flex-env-config

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  min_idle_instances: 0

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: <redacted-key>

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <redacted-instance-info>
```

Comment: The message you are getting "forbidden: The caller does 
not have permission" would suggest that the user does not have permissions to create a new service in App Engine. What roles does the account has?

Comment: I am working with the Owner account. As I mentioned, I was able to deploy the default service minutes before with no issues. This error happens only when I attempt to deploy a second service.

Comment: It may be worth to confirm that you are using the owner by running "gcloud auth list", there is a certain role in GCP which lets you deploy to existing services but not create new ones.

Comment: confirmed with `$ gcloud auth list` that I am using the owner account. If it was strictly a forbidden account issue, I think it would fail from the start, in this case, `$ gcloud app deploy` successfully downloads the container, builds the container up to **Step 14/18 : RUN bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash**, at this point it throws the error mentioned on the description, which means is possibly an issue related to the gems mentioned on the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error got fixed and deployment succeeded when removed this lines from `app.yaml`:

```
...
runtime_config:
  dotenv_config: flex-env-config
...
```

Not sure why this lines were important in the first place, investigate further and update with more meaningful explanation.